# Can realloc be used to change a **pointer to a *pointer?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

This code is from *Learn C The Hard Way* by Zed Shaw. In exercise 34 one of the practice problems is to implement a dynamic array, which is just an array of pointers enclosed in a struct.

The struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct DArray {
    int end;
    int max;
    size_t element_size;
    size_t expand_rate;
    void **contents;
};
```

To initialize one of these we use DArray_create()

```
DArray *DArray_create(size_t element_size, size_t initial_max)
{
    DArray *array = malloc(sizeof(DArray));
    array->max = initial_max;

    array->contents = calloc(initial_max, sizeof(void *));

    array->end = 0;
    array->element_size = element_size;
    array->expand_rate = 300;

    return array;
}
```

There is a also a function to resize the array:

```
static inline int DArray_resize(DArray *array, size_t newsize)
{
    array->max = newsize;

    void *contents = realloc(array->contents, array->max * sizeof(void *));

    array->contents = contents;

    return 0;
}
```

There are also some memory checks in there that I left out.

My question has to do with the way `calloc` and `realloc` are used. The first calloc in `DArray_create()` assigns to the `void **contents` double pointer in the array struct, which makes sense to me because it is an array of void pointers.

The realloc in `DArray_resize()` then resizes the memory but uses a `void *contents` single pointer which then replaces the original double pointer. Why is this OK? I have tested `DArray_resize()` using both a single pointer and a double pointer and they both seem to work. If the original `calloc` created a `void **` pointer, why is it OK for `realloc` to change it to  a `void *` pointer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`void *` is a special kind of pointer. It can be converted to and from any other type of data pointer.

`realloc` accepts and returns `void *`. It doesn't know what kind of pointer your program operates on. The caller has to convert your pointer to `void *` upon calling `realloc`, and convert the result back from`void *`. This conversion is so ubiquitous in C that it is done automatically.

Consider the original call to `calloc`.

```
array->contents = calloc(initial_max, sizeof(void *)); // <- returns void*
                                                       // gets converted to void**
```

`calloc` does not create a `void **` pointer. It returns a `void *` pointer (just like `realloc` does). It is the caller's responsibility co convert it to whatever pointer type is needed. The conversion happens upon assignment, but if you want, you can insert an explicit cast:

```
array->contents = (void **)calloc(initial_max, sizeof(void *));
```

Returning to `realloc`, the same thing happens there, only this time an explicit intermediate variable is used:

```
void *contents = realloc(array->contents, array->max*sizeof(void*)); // void* returned here
array->contents = contents; // converted to void** here
```

You can shift the conversion to the line where `realloc` is called if you want. It doesn't really matter where it is done.

```
void **contents = realloc(array->contents, array->max*sizeof(void*)); // converted here
array->contents = contents; // assignment, no conversion
```

There is also an implicit conversion of `array->contents` *to* `void*` when `realloc` is called. You can also use a cast here if you want:

```
void **contents = (void**)realloc((void*)array->contents, array->max*sizeof(void*));
```

... or an intermediate variable, or both. It doesn't really add anything to the quality of the program though, so this is not normally done.

Answer (score 3):

It's legal because `void *` has some special rules. Any object pointer (not function pointer) of type `T *` can be converted to `void*` and then back again to `T*` and the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

Also keep in mind that `realloc` returns `void *` so in `void *contents = realloc(...)` there is no conversion.